# Sidebar no longer shows up - it used to show up few days ago - no code change but has stopped working

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been using a Google Sheet with an attached Apps Script.
I have written the code myself and the code adds a custom menu as well as shows a Sidebar with various 'buttons'.

**Until recently (few weeks ago) everything used to work fine.**

*But now suddenly the Sidebar no longer shows up unless I go, click on the option in the custom menu.*

**How do I get it working again please?**

In the OnOpen function within the script I call the following:

```
    function onOpen() {
        // Code to create custom menu goes here
        showSideBarUserInterface();
    }

    function showSideBarUserInterface() {
        var html =      
 HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('SideBarUserInterface').evaluate()
                       .setWidth(UI_SIDEBAR_WIDTH)
                       .setTitle("What would you like to do?")
                       .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
    }
```

Comment: What do you see in the execution transcript? Have you tried writing some state information to the logs for testing?

Comment: In the code editor, choose the `onOpen()` function from the drop down list of function, and click the "run" button.  You may need to authorize a new permission.  If so, hopefully you will be prompted to accept the permissions needed.

Comment: @Sandy Good, what you are saying is correct - but I have already done that - I did re-authorise everything and refreshed the browser tab - still there is no change. Mind you the onOpen function seems to be already getting called since the Custom Menu does appear - it is just the SideBar does not show up.

Comment: @Dean Ramsevycz, strangely the execution transcript shows the error: Execution failed: You do not have permission to call showSidebar (line 556, file "Code").  But that is funny - it never used to do that before.

Comment: There was previously no "scope" (permission) needed to open a dialog box or sidebar.  Now there is.  The function name `onOpen` is a reserved function name, that is reserved for the Open event.  The `onOpen` function is a simple trigger.  A simple trigger, like `onOpen` will not execute any code that requires the user to authorize anything.  So, I'm guessing that there is a connection, and the reason for the different behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem recently and I finally went into the script editor edit menu and current project triggers and created an onOpen() trigger and that does the trick for me.  I didn't think that I had to do that with simple triggers but recently I add some additional functionality and so maybe that required authorization which maybe is why I need the installable version.  I don't really know the reason.  But it works.

Comment: But the onOpen function is getting called automatically - because my Custom menu does appear - it is just that SideBar does not show up on its own - it used to show up on its own before. Now I do have had the show sidebar action added as a menu option when I had written the code months ago - and if I go and select this option from the menu, then the Sidebar shows up - but not by itself.

Comment: My menu showed up also but I wasn't getting the sidebar until I added the onOpen in the edit menu.  I'm not saying I know why this is happening. I'm just saying that now it works for me and generally I move on to other problems after that.

Answer (score 1):

I have now removed the call to *showSideBarUserInterface()* from the *onOpen* function and instead created a trigger to call *showSideBarUserInterface* function directly when the spreadsheet is opened - rather than having a trigger which calls the *onOpen* function again.

In my view having a trigger which calls the onOpen function explicitly is a bad programming example - since it is supposed to be called automatically - but that is my view.

I do see that the *onOpen* function does run automatically when I open the spreadsheet so with the 'On spreadsheet open' trigger to run *showSideBarUserInterface* function everything seems to work as I want it to.